# Compare Misaligned Series columns Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, series, valueerror

Comparing 2 series objects of different sizes:

```
IN[248]:df['Series value 1']
Out[249]: 
0     70
1     66.5
2     68
3     60
4     100
5     12
Name: Stu_perc, dtype: int64

IN[250]:benchmark_value 
#benchamrk is a subset of data from df2 only based on certain filters
Out[251]: 
0    70
Name: Stu_perc, dtype: int64
```

Basically I wish to compare df['Series value 1'] with benchmark_value and return the values which are greater than 95% of benchark value in a column Matching list. Type of both of these is Pandas series. However sizes are different for both, hence it is not comparing.

**Input given:**

```
IN[252]:df['Matching list']=(df2['Series value 1']>=0.95*benchmark_value)
OUT[253]: ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

**Output wanted:**

```
 [IN]:
 df['Matching list']=(df2['Stu_perc']>=0.95*benchmark_value)
 #0.95*Benchmark value is 66.5 in this case.

 df['Matching list']
 [OUT]:
0     70
1     66.5
2     68
3     NULL
4     100
5     NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because benchmark_value is `Series`, for scalar need select first value of `Series` by [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html) and set `NaN`s by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
benchmark_value = pd.Series([70], index=[0])

val = benchmark_value.iat[0]
df2['Matching list']= df2['Stu_perc'].where(df2['Stu_perc']>=0.95*val)
print (df2)
     Stu_perc Matching list
0       70.0           70.0
1       66.5           66.5
2       68.0           68.0
3       60.0            NaN
4      100.0          100.0
5       12.0            NaN
```

General solution also working if `benchmark_value` is empty is `next` with `iter` for return first value of `Series` and if not exist use default value - here `0`:

```
benchmark_value = pd.Series([])

val = next(iter(benchmark_value), 0)
df2['Matching list']= df2['Stu_perc'].where(df2['Stu_perc']>=0.95*val)
print (df2)
    Stu_perc  Matching list
0       70.0           70.0
1       66.5           66.5
2       68.0           68.0
3       60.0           60.0
4      100.0          100.0
5       12.0           12.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :). Also can you please help in case I need TRUE FALSE Values . For examples true for values above 95% of benchmark 70 i.e. 66.5. So output should be TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor - Then use `df2['new'] = df2['Stu_perc']>=0.95*val`

Answer (score 1):

is your benchmark value is single-value?

If yes, you might need to convert `benchmark_value` which is a series to a number (without index) by using `df['Matching list']=(df['Stu_perc']>=0.95*benchmark_value.values)`

Comment: ValueError: Lengths must match to compare This is the error I get for above

Comment: hi, it's because df and df2 doesnt have the same length. I'm not sure if you are creating a new column on original df or df2.

Comment: New column on df is where I want the matching list column to be. df2 is only a temporary dataframe.

Comment: you can try the code edited above. Create a new column in `df` by compare each `df['Stu_perc']` element.

Answer (score 0):

It seems benchmark value is a Series with a single row, so not an actual number, I believe you need to *access* it first.

But this will return a list of Booleans. To get just the values that you want, you can use the `where` function.

Try this:

`df['Matching list']= df2['Stu_perc'].where(df2['Stu_perc'] >=0.95*benchmark_value[0][0]))`

Comment: Hi this is giving me output like this:   Matching list
 NaN
NaN
NaN
 60.0
NaN12.0

Comment: Basically it is giving NAN where I need values and vice verse

Comment: Sorry, I think I forgot a parenthesis, try with this:`d2['Matching list']= d2['Stu_perc'].where(d2['Stu_perc'] >= (0.95*benchmark_value[0][0]))`. I get the first result  you get, with NaN. Then, you can use `fillna()` on your Series to replace your NaN with 0.0.

Comment: IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

Comment: That's strange, it works for me. How did you create benchmark_value ?  I created it as a series with only one value: `benchmark_value = pd.DataFrame([70])`